# Draw a route using current location from device on map using GPS Provider

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps, android-location

I'm working on a project to display a route in a `MapView` based on current location from `GPS` Provider. I'm able to draw the path between two points but the problem starts when the location changes to a new point causing the draw path to erase.

Basically my Location Listener saves the current `GeoPoint` and sets the new `GeoPoint` location and after that it starts the overlay to draw a path based on those two points.I think an option could be saving the coordinates to a database and then pulling the information from there to draw the path.

Here is my code so far:

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {   

     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tracking device..",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            gp2 = new GeoPoint(
                    gp1.getLatitudeE6(),
                    gp1.getLongitudeE6());

            gp1 = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1000000),
                    (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1000000));


    myOverlay = new MapOverlay();

    mapOverlays_route.add(myOverlay);
    myMapView.invalidate();
}
}


class MapOverlay extends  com.google.android.maps.Overlay{

        public MapOverlay(){


        }


        public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){
         super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);

        //Configuring the paint brush

        Paint mPaint = new Paint();
         mPaint.setDither(true);
         mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
         mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
         mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
         mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
         mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);




         Point p1 = new Point();
         Point p2 = new Point();
         Path path1 = new Path();


         Path path2 = new Path();
         projection.toPixels(gp1, p1);
         projection.toPixels(gp2, p2);

         path1.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);//current location
         path1.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);//new location


         canvas.drawPath(path1, mPaint);//drawing the path

         }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, you need to have these coordinates stored somewhere.  These can be stored in a database or a more temporary local list. The draw method must also iterate between all of the coordinates you store.

Comment: Is storing and pulling the information from the database the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: For a temporary route, I would store it in a list.  If you want to store the values for later or have multiple paths plotted, I would go sqlite database.